# const and Virtual Inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, constants

```
struct Base{
    virtual void foo(){
        std::cout << "In Base\n";
    }
};
struct Derived : public virtual Base{
    virtual void foo() const{
        std::cout << "In Derived\n";
    }
};
Base* d = new Derived();

int main(int argc,char** args){
    d->foo();
    system("Pause");
}
```

When I run this code "In Base" is printed.  Why does having the const specifier change the inheritance?

Comment: Because it's a totally different overload?

Comment: @LogicStuff It is not a duplicate of that question, because in that question the base had the const function, in mine I have the derived as a const....This I would think would mean that the const modifier would not effect the orignal function (because it is only adding constness not taking away....)

Comment: @DarthRubik it doesn't matter which version is const and which isn't, the logic is the same either way. You're defining two different functions with two different signatures (but the same name).

Comment: @MarkRansom That is weird....you would think that It would complain if you where const in the base but not the derived, but if you were const in the derived but not in the base you would **think** that it would not matter....

Comment: @DarthRubik it might not be intuitive, but when you understand function signatures it makes perfect sense. It doesn't complain because you've defined two completely different, unrelated functions!

Comment: @MarkRansom Interesting...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `const` changes the signature of function.  So it's an [overload](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading) an not an [override](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overriding).

If you want to be sure not to make these kind of mistakes, you may use override.  This will detect these kind of mismatches and generate errors.

This would then fail to compile:

```
struct Base{
    virtual void foo(){
        std::cout << "In Base\n";
    }
};
struct Derived : public virtual Base{
    void foo() const override {    // <====  ouch: error because it's a different signature 
        std::cout << "In Derived\n";
    }
};
```

And this would compile succesfully:

```
struct Base{
    virtual void foo() const{
        std::cout << "In Base\n";
    }
};
struct Derived : public virtual Base{
    void foo() const override {    // <====  signatures do match
        std::cout << "In Derived\n";
    }
};
```

Comment: Actually, in this case it doesn't overload either...it hides.  You cannot call foo() on a non-const Derived unless you first cast it to Base.

Answer (score 2):

1. `virtual void foo()` and `virtual void foo() const` are two completely different functions. The `const` member function in the derived class does not override the non-`const` member function in the base class.
2. Given the choice of a `const` member function and a non-`const` member function, the non-`const` member function is given higher priority.